# How to fix smtp connection issue in mail sending?

Tags: python, smtp, erpnext, frappe

In my erpnext application I need to send bulk email and I am using `smtp.gmail.com`.
The number vary up to 1000. I can see system can send around 100 email successfully and then getting **Invalid Outgoing Mail Server or Port**. Further deep diving I can see mail exception in smtp login and message is: **Connection unexpectedly closed** from [frappe SMTP](https://github.com/frappe/frappe/blob/version-13/frappe/email/smtp.py#L267)

Problem found only in server (dev, live) but works fine in my local machine.

Following mail sending code is running inside a `for loop`.

```
frappe.enqueue(
                queue="short",
                method=frappe.sendmail,
                recipients=get_recipients(context.get('email')),
                sender=info@example.com,
                subject=frappe.render_template(
                    email_template.subject, context),
                message=message,
                now=False,
            )
```